# Setting the azure function timeout over 1 day

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I would like to ask you how to increase functionTimeout (in host.json) to more than 23:59:59 hours.

Currently, when I set more than 1 day or use a wildcard "-1" I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: If you need the function timeout to be that long, then I would suggest your code needs to be changed to fix it. That regex suggests you can't make it longer than `23:59:59` either.

Comment: This changes depending on the plan you use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout

Comment: @CSharpRock Hey so according to your documentation, if I am able to set 23:59:59 hours I should be also able to make it unlimited (but I cant).

Comment: Then open a support ticket

Answer (score 0):

You can use value of -1 for Unlimited timeout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).